# Service Broker Internal Activation Poisoning - Where?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, service-broker

I am experiencing poison messages and I am not sure why.

My broker setup looks like this:

```
CREATE MESSAGE TYPE
  [//DB/Schema/RequestMessage]
  VALIDATION = WELL_FORMED_XML;
CREATE MESSAGE TYPE
  [//DB/Schema/ReplyMessage]
  VALIDATION = WELL_FORMED_XML;

CREATE CONTRACT [//DB/Schema/Contract](
  [//DB/Schema/RequestMessage] SENT BY INITIATOR,
  [//DB/Schema/ReplyMessage] SENT BY TARGET
)

CREATE QUEUE Schema.TargetQueue

CREATE SERVICE [//DB/Schema/TargetService]
ON QUEUE Schema.TargetQueue (
  [//DB/Schema/Method3Contract]
)

CREATE QUEUE Schema.InitiatorQueue

CREATE SERVICE [//DB/Schema/InitiatorService]
ON QUEUE Schema.InitiatorQueue
```

Then I have my internal activation procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Schema.Import
AS

DECLARE @RequestHandle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
DECLARE @RequestMessage VARCHAR(8);
DECLARE @RequestMessageName sysname;

WHILE (1=1)
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRANSACTION;

  WAITFOR (
    RECEIVE TOP(1)
      @RequestHandle = conversation_handle,
      @RequestMessage = message_body,
      @RequestMessageName = message_type_name
    FROM
      Schema.TargetQueue

  ), TIMEOUT 5000;


  IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
  BEGIN
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    BREAK;
  END

  EXEC Schema.ImportStep1 @ID = @RequestMessage;
  --EXEC Schema.ImportStep2 @ID = @RequestMessage;

  END CONVERSATION @RequestHandle;

  COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
```

My activation is enabled by:

```
ALTER QUEUE Schema.TargetQueue
    WITH 
    STATUS = ON,
    ACTIVATION 
    ( STATUS = ON,
      PROCEDURE_NAME = Schema.Import,
      MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 10,
      EXECUTE AS SELF
    )
```

I initiate this process with this stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Schema.ImportStart
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @ID VARCHAR(8);

  DECLARE Cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT ID FROM OtherDatabase.OtherSchema.ImportTable
    EXCEPT
    SELECT ID FROM Table

  OPEN Cursor;
  FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor INTO @ID;
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @InitiateHandle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
    DECLARE @RequestMessage VARCHAR(8);

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    BEGIN DIALOG
      @InitiateHandle
    FROM SERVICE
      [//DB/Schema/InitiatorService]
    TO SERVICE
      N'//DB/Schema/TargetService'
    ON CONTRACT
      [//DB/Schema/Contract]
    WITH
      ENCRYPTION = OFF;

    SELECT @RequestMessage = @ID;

    SEND ON CONVERSATION
      @InitiateHandle
    MESSAGE TYPE
      [//DB/Schema/RequestMessage]
      (@RequestMessage);

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

    FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor INTO @ID;
  END
  CLOSE Cursor;
  DEALLOCATE Cursor;
END
```

So how this should work is:

- I execute ImportStart
- A message for each ID gets generated
- Internal activation makes Import steps execute

Instead, I get poison messaging and the queue becomes disabled.

If however,

- I I set Schema.TargetQue Activation to OFF
- EXEC schema.ImportStart
- EXEC schema.Import manually

It works fine.

Any insights anyone?

Comment: Are you seeing any log messages regarding the automatically activated procedure with additional details in your error log (normally you will)?  Without knowing anything else, the most likely culprit is authentication/authorization, but that's just a guess

Comment: I am not a server administrator, I only have db_owner permssions, so I cannot look the the logs without formally requesting it from my it department, which I guess I will go ahead and do.

If it was authentication/authorization how would you troubleshoot?  I have tried change the execute AS to Caller, self, a service account, and my username; all with no luck.

Comment: Depends a lot on what you're seeing for results really. Have you actually verified for example that messages are arriving on the queue and the procedure is actually getting to the point where it is attempting the receive vs. failing before that? If you have to request and wait for logs, you may want to consider adding a few print statements to your activated procedure temporarily at various spots to give you pointers on where the execution is getting to (prints get output to the log on activated procs also). Of course, this is all a guess at this point, it may very well not be auth at all.

Comment: Try this: `EXECUTE AS USER = '<queueowner>'; EXEC Schema.Import`. This will run the activated procedure in the same context as when activation occurs and you'll see whatever error occurs.

Comment: I actually just got this figured out, it looks like chadhoc was on the right track, in the logs it was throwing the error 

The activated proc '[Schema].[Import]' running on queue 'DB.Schema.TargetQueue' output the following:  'The server principal "hcaelxxam" is not able to access the database "database" under the current security context.

despite being db_owner.  After some googling, I found this article: technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187861.aspx

Because I was using two databases, impersonate permissions got denied.

ALTER DATABASE database SET TRUSTWORTHY ON

fixed it. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Well:

- Your message types are defined as `well_formed_xml`, yet you send `varchar(8)` as a message body. Does it really work?
- You use `[//DB/Schema/Method3Contract]` for the target queue, but do not define it. A misspelling, most likely.
- You specify `EXECUTE AS SELF` in the queue activation. BOL says some mystical thing about this case:

  > SELF
  >   Specifies that the stored procedure executes as the current user. (The database principal executing this ALTER QUEUE statement.)

I'm not really sure I understand the quoted statement, because it apparently contradicts with your experience. If it would be your user account, everything should have been fine, because you seem to have all permissions necessary to do the job.

So, just in case - who is the owner of the `Schema` schema? What permissions does this principal possess? And, if it's not you, who executes the `alter queue` statement (and why)?

Without access to logs, it's significantly more difficult to diagnose the problem, but I would start with creating a new user account with permissions identical to yours, setting it the owner of the `Schema` schema and then slowly working it down, revoking unnecessary permissions until it breaks. Assuming, of course, it will work at all.

Comment: 1. well_formed_xml as a varchar(8) does work, although I can see why it might be poor practice.  2. Method3Contract is a leftover from some jargon that I had (poorly) cleaned up before posting. 3. I figured out the answer was that impersonate permissions were getting denied (execute as failed) when the procedure tried to access the second database. Thanks though!

Comment: @hcaelxxam, the fact that you access an another database is a game changer in this case. If everything is located within a single DB, the `trustworthy` option is not required.